# Filtering doesn't work after a while

Tags: search, javafx, filtering, freeze

I'm using in my app [this example](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/) to let the user search/filter a table.

When you run the application, it works perfect.

The problem is when I left the program opened, minimized, and after a while (10-15min) I try to use it again. It's then when the search/filter doesn't work at all.

Here is the code:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    // 0. Initialize the columns.
    firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
    lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());

    // 1. Wrap the ObservableList in a FilteredList (initially display all data).
    FilteredList<Person> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(masterData, p -> true);

    // 2. Set the filter Predicate whenever the filter changes.
    filterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredData.setPredicate(person -> {
            // If filter text is empty, display all persons.
            if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }

            // Compare first name and last name of every person with filter text.
            String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

            if (person.getFirstName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches first name.
            } else if (person.getLastName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            return false; // Does not match.
        });
    });

    // 3. Wrap the FilteredList in a SortedList. 
    SortedList<Person> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);

    // 4. Bind the SortedList comparator to the TableView comparator.
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(personTable.comparatorProperty());

    // 5. Add sorted (and filtered) data to the table.
    personTable.setItems(sortedData);
       }                   
    }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that at all. It sounds a bit like an issue where a binding is being garbage collected, but I can't reproduce it even by forcing the garbage collector with `System.gc()` (which is usually a reliable way of reproducing those kind of bugs). Can you add some debugging to your code, e.g. add some logging or just `System.out.println(...)` to see if the listener on the text field is being invoked and if the predicate is being invoked?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code and it works for me.

However, step 2 must be the last step because the **filteredData.setPredicate** will be effective only after the second user input.

If someone just add a single letter, then the filtering will not happen.